# Unity Button.Image.Color won't "refresh"

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, button, colors, rgb

I am having a problem this morning with my Button.Image.Color

here is my really simple code :

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Red;
```

So this line perfectly works...Now, I am trying to use my own color onto that button with this, again, simple line of code :

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(106, 174, 23);
```

Well, the color actually changes...without changing...let's refer to the object itself while the game is running :

[My button / my color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR1PY.png)

So as you can see, the color changed but, it stays white.

I've looked at many posts in here but it appears that I am doing it right, obviously there is a mistake or else it would work fine, but even after reading a lot of posts it seems that I cannot see the solution on my own.

Answer (score 3):

Color accepts floats ranging from 0 - 1 for it's constructors.

You are setting them to 1 (anything above 1 is set to 1). And 1,1,1 = white.

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(0.415f, 0.682f, 0.09f);
```

This should give you the result you are looking for.

The numbers are generated by dividing your values by 255

Alternatively you could also parse your hexvalue:

```
if(Color.TryParseHtmlString("#75BF1A", out myColor))
{
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = myColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello and thanks for the answer, indeed Color needs number from 0 to 1.

Just to add to your answer I found that Color32 was the one I should have used since it takes the 0 - 255 values.

Thanks again have a great day!